# How to Disable Internet Explorer Hsts on Windows 10

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, https, hsts

Kb4487020 update  installed on windows 10 1703 computer. Then the internet explorer http page to https convert and the page does not open.

This is the same problem with Windows 7  February Montly Update.
Registry made the change on this problem has solved
Do you have this solved problem on windows 10 ?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3071338/internet-explorer-11-adds-support-for-http-strict-transport-security-s

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_DISABLE_HSTS]
"iexplore.exe"=dword:00000001

Answer (score -1):

**As it is a security feature, It is not recommended to disable HSTS.**

You can try to create same registry for win 10 that you had mentioned in your original post.

For testing purpose, You can try to disable the HSTS for IE by following the steps below.

(1) Press **Windows key + R** to open up a Run box. Then, type “**regedit**” and hit Enter to open Registry Editor.

(2) Using the left-pane of Registry Editor, navigate to the following registry subkey:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Internet Explorer \ Main \ FeatureControl .

(3) Right-click on FeatureControl and choose New > Key. Name it **FEATURE_DISABLE_HSTS** and press Enter to create the new key.

(4) Right-click on FEATURE_DISABLE_HSTS and choose New > **DWORD (32-bit)** value.

(5) Name the newly created DWORD to **iexplore.exe** and hit Enter to Confirm.

(6) Right-click on iexplore.exe and choose Modify. In the Value data box, type **1** and click Ok to save the changes.

> Note: If you’re on an x86-based system, you can save the changes,
>   reboot your computer and see if the method has been successful. If
>   you’re doing this on an x64-based system, continue with the next steps
>   below.

(7) Use the left pane again to navigate to the following registry subkey:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Wow6432Node \ Microsoft \ Internet
>   Explorer \ Main \ FeatureControl \

(8) Right-click on FeatureControl and choose New > Key, name it **FEATURE_DISABLE_HSTS** and hit Enter to save the changes.

(9) Right-click on FEATURE_DISABLE_HSTS and choose New > DWORD (32-bit) value and name it **iexplore.exe**.

(10) Double-click on **iexplore.exe** and change the Value data box to **1** and hit Ok to save the changes.

(11) Reboot your computer and see if the HSTS settings have been disabled for Internet Explorer at the next startup.

Reference:

[Clearing or Disabling HSTS settings in Internet Explorer](https://appuals.com/how-to-clear-or-disable-hsts-for-chrome-firefox-and-internet-explorer/)

Comment: Registry entries do not work when done on windows 10.But Windows 7 also works.

Comment: I can see that you had applied group policy for 64 bit system. Here, I want to confirm with you that, did you created 2 registry keys on your systems as shown in above steps?

Comment: I have created two registery keys (34/64 Bit). But there was no change.